# Using Index and match returning error: 'A value is not available to the formula or function'

Tags: excel

I am trying to use Index and match combination to retrieve values in a column where the date from my table matches the date from another table. This is the formula:

```
=INDEX(BTL!A2:G262, MATCH(A2, BTL!A2:G262,0), MATCH("Overbooked?", BTL!B1:G262))
```

This is the table where I am using the formula:

[image]

This is the BTL table:

[image]

The error that is being returned is 'A value is not available to the formula or function'.

What's the reason for this?

Comment: `MATCH("Overbooked?", BTL!B1:G262)` should be something like `MATCH("Overbooked?", BTL!B1:G1, 0)` (I don't see the column and row numbers) and `MATCH(A2, BTL!A2:G262,0)` should be `MATCH(A2, BTL!A2:A262,0)`

Comment: I have amended the formula to this: =INDEX(BTL!A2:G262, MATCH(A2, BTL!A2:A262,0), MATCH("Overbooked?", BTL!B1:G1, 0)) But it is still showing the same error. The columns in the BTL table go from A-G left to right

Comment: Do the following test: Type into E1: `=A2=BTL!A3` to check if the two dates are recognized as the same (I assume the first table's first row should lookup the second tables second row, I mean both are 2021-04-01).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've managed to resolve the issue.  See answer below

Answer (score 0):

The MATCH function returns the position of the lookup value in a 1-dimensional array. Imagine a row or a column. `=MATCH(A2, BTL!A2:G262,0)` will return an error because A2:G262 is a 2-D array. `=MATCH(A2, BTL!A2:A262,0)` has correct syntax but may still return an error if A2 isn't found. The absence of absolute referencing (like `=MATCH(A2, BTL!$A$2:$A$262,0)` makes the formula unfit for copying.

The same applied to `MATCH("Overbooked?", BTL!B1:G262)`, except that B1:G262 isn't anywhere near the range you want to search. I think you mean the column and, therefore, must search in B1:G1.

Of course, if either of your MATCH functions returns an error the entire formula can't return a proper result either. Test the MATCH functions separately before inserting them into your INDEX function. You can also select them in the finished formula and press F9. Finally, you may like to guard against that by enclosing the formula in an IFERROR() function.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(BTL!A2:G262, =MATCH(A2, BTL!A2:A262,0), MATCH("Overbooked?", BTL!B1:G1, 0)),"ERR")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have changed the formula to: =INDEX(BTL!A2:G262, MATCH(A2, BTL!A2:A262,0), MATCH("Overbooked?", BTL!B1:G1, 0)). I am still receiving the same error. I have narrowed it down to =MATCH(A2, BTL!A2:A262,0) being the cause of the problem (this is the part of the formula that is returning the error but I can't understand why? I have also tried to include the absolute referencing: =MATCH(A2, BTL!$A$2:$A$262,0) but this hasn't made a difference

Comment: The $ signs will only make a difference when you copy the formula to other cells. If ` =MATCH(A2, BTL!A2:A262,0)`, entered on its own, gives an error the reason should be because there is an error in A2 or in BTL!A2:A262. Check the spelling of the sheet name. You are very, very close to finding the error.

Comment: Thank you for your help Variatus. I have managed to resolve the issue (see my answer above). It seems it was something to do with the formatting of the date column. Very frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by selecting the date column in the table where I was using the formula and using the 'text to columns' feature under the data tab. I selected the 'column data format' as 'date' and DMY